# Create dynamic menu for Laravel project using Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I’m creating a new website with Laravel and use Voyager as admin panel for my website.

The problem is let’s assume that we want to create a menu with menu builder for all categories, so when we add or delete a category it will be also added/deleted from our menu and use it on my frontend.

Like as I saw with the menu builder we can just add a static item with it’s route.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to programmatically manage menus with Voyager is to work directly with the `menus` and `menu_items` tables directly.

In the Voyager admin panel, the menus are configured with [BREAD](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/bread/introduction). There is [an open Github issue](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1030) to make BREAD available programmatically, which would then allow one to manage the menus programmatically, but it has not been developed yet.