# How to catch the category to put it in my dynamic menu with voyager and laravel

Tags: php, routes, laravel-8, voyager

I am a beginner in laravel and voyager. I would like to create a dynamic menu of the categories of my posts. I created a main menu corresponding to my post categories but I can't find how to associate it with my categories dynamically on voyager.
[What should I put in place of "Route for the menu item"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR3ni.png)
I would also like to replace the name of my item with an image that is not a font icon of voyager font class. Is it possible ?

I tried to create my route with this :

use App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController;
Route::resource('categories', CategoriesController::class);

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Never used Voyager, but few years ago such thread exists:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080641/create-dynamic-menu-for-laravel-project-using-voyager

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.